# create-react-app is too slow and creates messy apps

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am learning react and not exprienced too much. Whenever I want to create a new react project, the `create-react-app` command takes a lot of time making one. I have followed [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) which creates react apps really fast and they are simple and clean unlike ones made by create-react-app, which are too complicated and messy. Is there a boilerplate to help me creating simple react apps quickly?

Comment: if you want to create simple react apps you should not use create-react-app because its a overkill. but if you wanto create big complex apps then you should use it

Comment: You can use cloud IDE like: https://repl.it/languages/reactjs and
https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I don't want to use online programs. I want to use simple offline programs. Please suggest me a good boilerplate

Answer (score 17):

This is the easiest way to get started

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Below is an alternative, but it's a lot more involved.

```
mkdir my-app // create directory
cd my-app
npm init -y //create package.json
npm install react react-dom //install react and react-dom
touch index.js index.css
```

You can add your code to index.js. It will looks something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Hello World</div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

After that you'll need to get your babel

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server babel-loader css-loader style-loader html-webpack-plugin

touch webpack.config.js
```

Configure your webpack

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin =  require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry : './my-app/index.js',
    output : {
        path : path.resolve(__dirname , 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        rules : [
            {test : /\.(js)$/, use:'babel-loader'},
            {test : /\.css$/, use:['style-loader', 'css-loader']}
        ]
    },
    mode:'development',
    plugins : [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
            template : 'my-app/index.html'
        })
    ]

}
```

Add babel presets and npm command to build (build) and run (dev) your code to package.json

```json
"main": "index.js",
"babel": {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
},
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open"
}
```

Comment: You have a mistake here
}"scripts": {
it must be },"scripts": {
Plus, you don't provide any script to launch the server such as npm start

Answer (score 5):

The best and most effiecient way is to first install `pnpm` package. It's much faster than normal `npm install` or `npm i` command due to symlinks and cache implemented in it.

It's better to have a git repository which is initiated by `create-react-app`, you can install the packages you commonly use in the `package.json` file. Then each time you want to create a new project, you can clone the repository and install the packages fast by running the following command. It may takes the same time as before, because `pnpm` needs to cache the packages and re-use them.

```
pnpm i
```

> I have created a sample repository, you can clone it from [this link](https://github.com/mostafaghadimi/ReactStarter).

**P.S 1**:You can read more about `pnpm`, in [this link](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm).

Answer (score 1):

Use

npm init vite@latest

Or

Yarn create vite@latest

It will ask you a question and you have to answer it and it creates and run react apps tooo faster than the original cli

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion use `yarn` instead `npm`. I heard it is faster:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Then for making a directory for your projects:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

For checking version:

```
yarn --version
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I do this fast is by running `npx create-react-app boilerplate`
and then save that directory and push it to github.

then you can just get your new react app by simply cloning that repo.
by running `git clone boilerplate` and then you can just rename the folder, and the name of the app and other information you need in package.json.
I really only edit the name and the source repo in the `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [installing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app-offline) `create-react-app-offline`:

1. Install it with `npm install -g create-react-app-offline`
2. Now go to your directory and create your app with `crao -n my-app`

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDN link for any temporary projects and start doing them. This may require an internet connection to run.

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Use these 3!
And for reference - [React CDN Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm reopening the topic, but I found a solution like this.

```bash
git clone 'url' 
git init
cd 'directory with the clone'
npx create-creat-app <app-name>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).